# SQL Server : restore database - why are file names all the same?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, restore

I am relatively new to SQL Server, so bear with me.

SQL Server 2008 R2, on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1

I am restoring a production database into a test database (for electronic medical records). I right click on the test DB and select `Tasks --> Restore --> Database`. I find the desired `.bak` file (in this case, `NGProd_data_dump.bak`).

In the options section, under "Restore the database files as:" table, all of the files have the same value in the rightmost column. I'm told by one of my colleagues that I have to manually rename all of them. Why? Is this right? See the screenshot. All the `.ndf` files are the same name and apparently they have to be unique.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I'm not even sure I'm asking the right question. Help would be appreciated.

[image: Restore Options window]

Comment: The first time you do a restore, you need to manually ensure those file names are correct.  If you restore the same backup over the same database again, it usually retains the correct names going forward.  At least in my experience, this is true.

Comment: What I'm confused about is why they all default to the same name and why I would _ever_ have to manually rename them, even once. It makes me think I'm doing the process wrong somehow.

Comment: I ask myself this question all the time.  As far as I'm aware, you're not doing anything wrong.